# No access to remote repository

Tags: node.js, git, deployment

I am deploying my node.js app.

I am using git hooks and creating a remote repository.

In the image below you can see that i have added the remote 'adiproduction' to which i will push from my local repo.
[image]

Below i am pasting the image of content in post-receive file of hooks.
[image]

Following is the error when i try to push my code on 'adiproduction' remote.
**ubuntu@35.154.65.179: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.**

[image]

Edit:
I tried running the `ssh -Tv ubuntu@35.154.65.179` command. And i got the following output.

[image]

Comment: To debug this, take Git entirely out of the equation. Run `ssh -Tv ubuntu@35.154.65.179` and observe the key exchange process. What key(s) are you sending? What key(s) should you be sending instead? Figure this out and fix your ssh configuration. Git will then work, because Git literally just runs ssh here, so once ssh works, so does Git.

Comment: @torek i have add the screenshot of this command. Please review and tell me.

Comment: Your `ssh` command found two keys to offer, both from your ssh agent. One was an ED25519 key and one was an RSA key. Neither was accepted. The public key files corresponding to the two offered keys are in `/home/mobcoder/.ssh/id_ed25519` (probably plus `.pub`, ssh sometimes leaves the extension off the debug output) and `/home/mobcoder/.ssh/id_rsa` (also probably plus `.pub`). That means the server *on* `35.154.65.179` doesn't have either of these keys in its `authorized_keys` file for user `ubuntu`.

Answer (score 0):

try to run the code with "sudo"
sudo helps you to run the command with root privilege

and secondly, if you dont want use sudo so please set the ssh key on your git account, this link will helps you to set the ssh key-
**'https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-linux-unix/'**

and lastly if above solution not helps then please delete the current repository and try to clone again useing following command with ssh clone link-

git clone -b

thank you